# how can I select all columns without any duplicates in a particular column with sql

Tags: sqlite

I need to select all the columns of any record that has a distinct value in a particular columns so if I have

```
Firts|Last|State|
Jacck|Redy|NJ
Jacck|Redy|NJ
Jacck|Redy|NY
Jacck|Redy|NY
Jacck|Redy|OH
Jacck|Redy|OH
```

I would like to get

```
 Jacck|Redy|NJ
 Jacck|Redy|NY
 Jacck|Redy|OH
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select first, last, state from table1 GROUP BY first, last, state
```

OR

```
 select distinct first, last,state from table1
```